# Background image of UIScrollView doesn't appear on screen

Tags: ios, image, uiscrollview

Why does the background image won't appear on my scroll view?

```
-(void) loadView {
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
    UIView *menuView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:screenRect];
    self.view = menuView;

    UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Spacemenu.jpg"];

    UIScrollView *menuScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    menuScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    menuScrollView.contentSize = backgroundImage.size;
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:backgroundImage];
    [self.view addSubview:menuScrollView];
    [self.view insertSubview:imageView belowSubview:menuScrollView];
}
```

I want to make a scroll view which scrolls horizontally to a long rectangular image at the background. Please help

Comment: removing .jpg from the imageName doesn't help.

Comment: have you tried specifying the frame for your imageView?  imageView.frame = self.view.bounds;  for example

Comment: @JeromeDiaz I was thinking that the imageView will be very long and the scroll view will be used to do the panning horizontally on the screen. Therefore, self.view.bound is not what i want.

Comment: @JeromeDiaz i tried doing what you told, still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
menuScrollView.contentSize = backgroundImage.size;
```

set the `contentSize` in `viewDidAppear`

And if you want to pan image using scroll view, you must add the `imageView` to `scrollView`, not to `self.view.`

Answer (score 0):

here is a code I use to put a background image below a tableView, should work with a scrollview (tableview inherit from scrollview)

```
UIImageView *backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
backgroundImage.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view insertSubview:backgroundImage atIndex:0];
self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = nil;
```

By adapting it:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...

    //create your scrollView
    menuScrollView.backgroundView = nil;
    menuScrollView.backgroundColor = nil;

    UIImageView *backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
    backgroundImage.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view insertSubview:backgroundImage atIndex:0];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your `scrollView` to your `self.view`:

`[self.view addSubview:menuScrollView]`

then:

`[menuScrollView addSubview:imageView]`

Let me know what happens. ;)

Comment: It;s okay i solved it. Its the problem with the image format.